# HTTPEntity Giving a null value

Tags: java, php, android

I have a forgot password page on my Android app. If I enter in no email it returns the correct response from the server, and if I enter in an email that is found in our database then it sends the user an email and returns the correct response from the server. However if I enter in an email and it is not found in our database, when I call

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

entity is a null value. I'm not sure why it would work for 2 of the cases but not the third.

Does anyone know why that would be? My code is as follows

Android Code:

```
private void accessURL(String url) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    if (url.equalsIgnoreCase(Global.forgotPasswordURL)) {
        InputStream is = null;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.getText().toString()));

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if(entity != null){
                is = entity.getContent();
                String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(is).toString();
                if (jsonResult.equalsIgnoreCase("Please enter your Email")) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Please Enter Your Email Address")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // continue with delete
                                }
                            }).show();
                }else if(jsonResult.equalsIgnoreCase("Email Address Not Found")){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("The Email Address You Entered has not Been Found").setMessage("Make sure that you entered your email correctly.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    }).show();
                }else{
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Your Email Has Been Found!").setMessage("Check the email you provied for further instructions on resetting your password.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    }).show();
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Null", "null");
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

PHP Code:

```
if (isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","***********","******","*******");
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tempusers WHERE email = '$email'");
        $ans = mysql_num_rows($query);
        $ans2 = mysql_num_rows($query2);
        $str = $ans . " " . $ans2;
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0 && mysql_num_rows($query2) == 0){
            sendResponse(205, "Email Address Not Found");
            return false;
        }
        $temp = false;
        if(mysql_num_rows($query2) != 0){
            $temp = true;
            $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tempusers WHERE email = '$email'");
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
            mailUser($email, $row['firstname'], $temp);

            sendResponse(200, "Email Address Found".$str);
            return true;
        }else{
            $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
            mailUser($email, $row['firstname'], $temp);

            sendResponse(200, "Email Address Found".$str);
            return true;
        }
    }
    sendResponse(400, 'Please enter your Email');
    return false;
```

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it behaves according to specification of [`HttpEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html) for 205 responses. Here is what the spec says:

> HTTP messages can carry a content entity associated with the request
>   or response. Entities can be found in some requests and in some
>   responses, as they are optional. Requests that use entities are
>   referred to as entity enclosing requests. The HTTP specification
>   defines two entity enclosing request methods: POST and PUT. Responses
>   are usually expected to enclose a content entity. **There are exceptions**
>   to this rule such as responses to HEAD method and 204 No Content, 304
>   Not Modified, **205 Reset Content** responses.

In case if email was not found you can send 404 response code in PHP and check in your Java code:

```
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404){
  //email was not found
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The only reason I have that status code as different from the others is because on the iPhone version of the app I needed a 3rd status code in order to differentiate between the 3 different cases, so I just picked another code.

Answer (score 1):

send same 200 code for email not found as well

```
sendResponse(200, "Email Address Not Found");
```